# get_current_site() not returning site name

Tags: multisite, functions, codex

The function [`get_current_site()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_site) that's in my themes' footer.php file doesn't return the 'site name' property as specified in the docs (and expected in the theme). The purpose of the function is to return all details about the parent site on a multi-site setup.

The only return values I am getting are the blog_id and path. eg:

```
<?php print_r(get_current_site());?>
```

Returns:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [domain] => www.mydomain.co.uk [path] => / [blog_id] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `get_current_site_name()` to insure you get the site name so something like this:

`echo get_current_site_name(get_current_site());`

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but `get_current_site_name()` has been deprecated; use this `get_current_site()->site_name` or `get_current_site()->domain` for the domain without the text "Sites" at the end.

Comment: Great answer Squiggler, thanks for adding it for others who come across this! Welcome to WPSE btw. Please feel free to [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour). :)